# Java SWT Refresh Multiple Shells From Button

Tags: java, swt

I am building an app that accesses a database and currently I have a SWT Shell that displays the main table. From this table users can open individual records and from inside the records form the user can open a second form that is of the same type but contains different data.
If the record in either form is updated the update is reflected in the main form.
My problem is I can't update the first record form that is opened.
Is there a way to force an update or redraw for all open forms of a certain type or is there a way I can update multiple shell of the same type at the same time.
The screen shot below shows what I am trying to do.

[image]

Screenshot details

- A
  - Main Form
  - This form currently gets updated when either of the 2 secondary forms change data in the database. This is done by reloading the table from the secondary forms
- B
  - This is the first instance of the data form
- C
  - This is the second instance of the data form.
  - It is opened from first data form by clicking the open button. What I am trying to do is have the first data form refresh when I change something in the second form.
  - For example I opened the record for the tag 295 White and when I update the data for this record I want the changes to be shown in the record form for 26 White

I know this is a hard to understand question, so feel free to ask for more details I am pulling my hair out trying to figure this out.

Comment: Your second data form needs the instance of the first data form and the instance of the main form passed to it.  That way, you can call methods on the other data forms from the second data form.  You'll probably need a global Stack of data form instances, as you can keep opening new data forms.  You'd push the instance on the stack when the form is created, and pop the instance from the stack when the form is closed.

Comment: What would be the best way to get the instance so that I can send it? Or better yet how do I go about setting up a global stack?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the main form, you set up a Java `Stack`.

```
Stack<DataForm> stack = new Stack<DataForm>();
```

You pass a reference of this `Stack` to the data form(s).

In the constructor of the data form, you pass the data form instance.

```
stack.push(this);
```

In the destructor of the data form (on exit), you remove the data form instance.

```
int pos = stack.search(this);
stack.remove(pos);
```

When you want to refresh all of the forms, you loop through the stack.

```
for (DataForm dataForm : stack) {
     // do the refresh
}
```

Comment: I had to make a get method to pull the instance sine the 'this' variable was pulling the event handler. Things appear to be working now Thanks,