# Java SWT opening multiple windows

Tags: java, swt

I have a GUI built with Java SWT widgets and I'm trying to have multiple windows. From my main `Shell`, I create a new `Shell` with it as its parent. In the new window, I have `Buttons` and `Labels` and update the text in the `Labels`. For some reason, when a 2nd new window is created and I return to the first window, the second labels are updated and not the current window. The way I open the new window is:

```
NewWindow newWindow = new NewWindow(mainShell, 1, 2);
newWindow.open();
```

and the `NewWindow` class is:

```
public class NewWindow {
    Shell newShell;

    public NewWindow(Shell mainShell, int first, int second) {
        newShell = new Shell(mainShell, SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.MIN);
        newShell.setSize(629, 557);
        newShell.setText("New Window");
        newShell.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);
    }

    public void open() {
        newShell.open();
    }

    public void close() {
        newShell.setVisible(false);
    }

}
```

The arguments passed in are used to define parameters in each window that are different for the windows buttons and controls. I must be missing or messing up something. The answer at [Java SWT Refresh Multiple Shells From Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564503/java-swt-refresh-multiple-shells-from-button) looks like something I may need to implement but I'm having an issue using it. How should I fix this issue?

Comment: I don't think there is enough of your code here for us to be able to say anything about the problem. Where are the Buttons and Labels?

Comment: This is just a snippet. The actual code is really lengthy. The buttons and labels are private static fields in NewWindow and are created after the new Shell is created

Comment: If they are `static` there will only be one instance of them and all your windows are changing the same labels and buttons. They should probably not be static. But without seeing more code we can't say for sure.

Comment: @greg-449 You're absolutely right! I was being careless and that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the your Question properly, but i think while you opened the second window, first window is getting updated without the change in second window. If this is your question then. Try changing you code in 'open' as follows. This makes the second shell in a live state and the control will not go to the first shell until you close it.

```
   public void open() {

      newShell.open();
       while (!newShell.isDisposed()) {
             if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                 display.sleep();
             }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to open the windows multiple times, rather try the concept of 'Wizards' in SWT Framework. With 'Wizard', you can navigate from page to another page as well.